# What is the best way to setup and test Lambda API?

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-api-gateway

Wanting to build a microservice within Lambda.

I want it to be accessible via an HTTP request so I believe I need to configure it with API gateway. I am unsure if I should use `API Gateway Proxy Request Event` or `API Gateway Proxy Response Event`.

Also in terms of authenticating the user, what is the best way?

I am thinking using Auth0 so a user will essentially just send a JWT with the HTTP request.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use API Gateway Proxy Request. I configure the `Integration Request` to use `Use Lambda Proxy integration` which will result in `Integration Response` updating to `Proxy integrations cannot be configured to transform responses.`

I then handle responses within the lambda function itself. For example, I will have the following for a successful response:

```
context.succeed({
  statusCode: 200,
  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'Application/json'},
  body
});
```

And for an example of an expected fail, I have:

```
context.succeed({
  statusCode: 404,
  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'Application/json'},
  body: JSON.stringify({'Error': error})
});
```

**NOTE:** It is important to note I use `context.succeed` on error handling and not `context.fail`.

I developed my lambda locally in Node and used a combination of `lambda-local` and `lambda-tester` for debugging/testing functionality. For example, I would run the following command to pass in the lambda and the event:

`lambda-local  -f ~/Desktop/lambdaNode/myNewAPI.js -e ~/Desktop/lambdaEvents/testEvent.json`

An example event will look like this:

```
{
      "queryStringParameters":
      {
          "param1":    "1234567890",
          "param2":    "0987654321",
      }
}
```

For my unit tests, I used `lambda-tester` along with mocha as follows:

```
const LambdaTester = require( 'lambda-tester' );
describe('handle my new lambda: ', () => {

  it('should do exactly what I expect', () => {
    return LambdaTester( myNewAPI.handler )
      .event( testEvents.newLambdaEvent )
      .expectSucceed( ( result ) => {
        expect( result.statusCode ).to.equal(200);
      });
  });
});
```

Test the above with `npm test` if you're setup for that, otherwise just `mocha testFile`

For my use case, authentication is handled differently as it is an internal API. For your case, I think JWT is the best way forward there, although I am sorry I cannot provide more info in that regard.

Comment: Is there any way to develop this locally? I had a look at an npm package lambda-local but couldn't find any way to test an http request on the lambda function. What environment did you develop your script in?